# Stream with for loop not returning every result - Flutter

Tags: firebase, loops, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use a `Stream` with a loop inside a `StreamBuilder`, but I'm only getting the first result.
I'm using this structure because I need to loop through an array of Items and get only the ones that contain that certain document in Firebase. Could someone please help me figure this out?
This is my `Stream` with the nested loop:

```
Stream getProductModels(list) {
    var stream;
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      stream = databaseReference
          .collection('XXXX')
          .where('XXXX', isEqualTo: list[i])
          .snapshots();
    }
    return stream;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to merge several `stream`s into one `stream`.
There is a Flutter SDK for this.

https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart

You can use `MergeStream` or `ZipStream`.

Hope this is helpful for you.